# Can I get access to router locale interface from internet?

Tags: router, modem, cisco

Standart local address of router is 192.168.1.1 to administration interface. Can I get access to router from internet if I know IP adress of local network and IP of router?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First open your router to settings from internet is a big security risk.

But depending on your router should have an option like

- Turn Remote Management On

[Remote-access-router-from-outside-my-home](http://www.cnet.com/forums/discussions/remote-access-router-from-outside-my-home-304080/)

Comment: You can't access your device over the Internet by it's local IP address. You need to know the external IP address or URL (dynamic DNS). You can enable this by turning on remote management but change the access credentials.

Comment: @BrianB That is just what i say. Turn Remote Management ON.